# What are some recommended open source tools for web browser history analysis?

Tags: web-browser, forensics

I'm looking at a series web browser histories from various browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc) and need to do some analysis.  All of these browsers store data much differently, but I was wondering if there was an open-source tool suite out there that would help me to analyze all of them.  If this is just wishful thinking, are there any open-source tools commonly used or is this type of analysis usually done manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web Historian](http://www.mandiant.com/products/free_software/web_historian/) - not open source, but free (as in beer)

"MANDIANT Web Historian helps users review the list of websites (URLs) that are stored in the history files of the most commonly used browsers, including: Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome."

[Odessa](http://odessa.sourceforge.net/) - just for IE, but open source

Answer (score 2):

Another (not open source, but free) solution will be to use Nir Sofer's tools (you can find them [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/)) with a batch file (built by you..)

Nir offers Cookies/Protected storage/Cache/History query software for all of the big browsers, that can be used through the console (he provides the flags and tutorials on his site for each freeware).

Since all of Nir's output files are exactly the same,  you can write a simple batch file that will dump all of the outputs to the same file and then analyse them with a program of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Would be happy to know of any particular open-source tool that helps with analyzing all browsers.

One resource I bumped into which seems reasonably up-to-date and covers IE, Firefox and Chrome is [Digital Forensics with Open Source Tools: Using Open Source Platform Tools for Performing Computer Forensics on Target Systems: Windows, Mac, Linux, Unix, Etc (Cory Altheide, Harlan Carvey)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=J8h8VWUmDuYC&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=forensic+open+source+browser&source=bl&ots=mSspdYwd6-&sig=a-44eWdHskXrifkVtqxGhsItYas&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ckExT5GFL8fJswbVo9yABA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=forensic%20open%20source%20browser&f=false). The link is to the google books online version, which has some pages missing.